# "Probabilistic" One-Hot-Encoder for transformers library

Tags: classification, huggingface

I'm using the transformers library to fine-tune a LLM for classification.

However, my problem is a bit particular, as the labels are hierarchical, that is, in the form A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2 etc.

Sometimes, I only have the first part (e.g. "A"). I'd like to use those "incomplete" datas in my training dataset, so my idea was to use a "Probabilistic" One-Hot-Encoder as target (or, to be more correct, to give a modified softmax target). For exemple, I know that in the "A*" class I have 1/3 of samples that are A-1 and 2/3 A-2, when I have a A-?, I would have a target softmax of [1/3, 2/3, 0, ...,0].

But in transformers I didn't find a way to do that "easily", as for classification you have to give integers to the model. Do you know if it is doable ?

Thank you !

Comment: Integer labels are mandatory only when using the sparse categorical cross-entropy loss, in the other case you should be able to provide vectors as labels unless it's a specific limitation of the lib you're using.